# How to retrieve @IndexedEmbedded properties?

Tags: hibernate-search

FullTextQuery.setProjection("id", "author") ignored author's id, name property. How can I retrieve these properties?

```
@MappedSuperclass
class BaseContent{
  @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "author.", includePaths = {"id", "name"}) @ManyToOne
  Author author;
}
@Entity @Indexed
class Content extends BaseContent{
  @Id @DocumentId
  Integer id;
}
@Entity
class Author{
  @Id
  Integer id;
  @Field(store = Store.YES)
  String name;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Is this query correct?.

```
FullTextQuery ftq = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Content.class);

    ftq.setProjection("id", "author.id", "author.name");
    ftq.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Content.class));

    List<Content> result = ftq.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `author.` prefix.

```
fullTextQuery.setProjection("author.id", "author.name")
```

---

**EDIT**: Did you try inspecting the results *without* your transformer? It should return a `List<Object[]>` with the content of the projections. If it does, then it's the *transformer* that isn't working. I very much doubt that `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` is able to handle composite aliases such as "author.name". You'll probably need you own transformer.

Also note that:

- If you just want to get the Content entity, and getting it from the database doesn't bother you, just remove the projection and result transformer: Hibernate Search will get a `List<Content>` from the database for you.
- If what you're trying to do is to avoid loading anything from the database, then you're on the right path. But as I said, you'll probably need a custom transformer.

Comment: Default prefix stored correctly. Searching correctly. But why can't retrieve it?

Comment: @hurelhuyag Your example does not use the prefix when calling `setProjection`... Can you give us the exact code you are using to search, from building the full query to calling "list()" on the resulting query?